# WatchKit tableview fixed group

Tags: swift, watchkit

Is it possible to have a fixed group in the WKInterfaceController while having a table?

I have tried to put the table and my fixed "views" in separate groups, but it does not work at all.

Comment: No, I believe it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: As 'Mike' said the table won't scroll inside a fixed group, but it will if the group is sized to fit its content. You could, and this is something cool (I think), create a non-scrollable table inside a fixed group. Place some buttons aside and call yourTable.scrollToRowAtIndex(yourIndex). Now you will have some nicely animated view in the middle, which will present some content and also could be selectable if needed. It's an Idea that I've got yesterday. :)